# Run Oracle Query using VBA

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

When i run the below script i'm getting "TYPE MISMATCH" Error

'Getting error when i execute below code

```
query1 = "Select count(*) from test" & _
Query2 = query1 & "where proc_d" & _
Query3 = Query2 & "IN('10 jun 2015')"
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code - copy and paste the *actual* code and format it using the {} button.  And *indent* it !  Also, if you're getting an error, you should identify which line(s) are the problem.  Looking at the part where you're constructing the SQL, that doesn't even look like valid VBA - you use a line continuation but then do not continue the line...

Comment: Hi Tim, Can i post only part of the code where i'm getting error. As I trying to post complete code but unable to post.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that

```
query1 = "Select count(*) from test" & _
Query2 = query1 & "where proc_d" & _
Query3 = Query2 & "IN('10 jun 2015')"
```

becomes

```
query1 = "Select count(*) from test" & Query2 = query1 & "where proc_d" & Query3 = Query2 & "IN('10 jun 2015')"
```

after combining lines together.

Change it to

```
query1 = "Select count(*) from test " & _
         "where proc_d " & _
         "IN('10 jun 2015')"
```

Note also the addition of the extra space after the words "test" and "proc_d".  Without those spaces the SQL command will be constructed, but will be invalid.

Comment: Thank you very much for user suggestions.

Comment: your suggestions*